# OpenIDM - Scripted Groovy connector provider

Tags: groovy, openidm

I am trying to generate the provider configuration for a scripted groovy connector (not a **REST/CREST connector**) using the **Groovy ScriptedConnector** connector.

When I send the following configuration to the **CreateFullConfig REST service** (/openidm/system?_action=createFullConfig), I issue an *500 internal server error*.

> {
>   "name" : "scriptedGroovy",
>   "connectorRef": {
>   "bundleName": "org.forgerock.openicf.connectors.groovy-connector",
>   "bundleVersion": "1.4.1.0",
>   "connectorName": "org.forgerock.openicf.connectors.groovy.ScriptedConnector"
>   },
>   "configurationProperties": {
>   "authenticateScriptFileName": "AuthenticateScript.groovy",
>   "warningLevel": 1,
>   "minimumRecompilationInterval": 100,
>   "deleteScriptFileName": "DeleteScript.groovy",
>   "schemaScriptFileName": "SchemaScript.groovy",
>   "scriptRoots": null,
>   "customizerScriptFileName": null,
>   "resolveUsernameScriptFileName": null,
>   "customConfiguration": null,
>   "debug": false,
>   "targetDirectory": null,
>   "disabledGlobalASTTransformations": null,
>   "classpath": ["path/connector/tools"],
>   "scriptExtensions": [
>   "groovy"
>   ],
>   "testScriptFileName": "TestScript.groovy",
>   "customSensitiveConfiguration": null,
>   "updateScriptFileName": "UpdateScript.groovy",
>   "sourceEncoding": "UTF-8",
>   "searchScriptFileName": "SearchScript.groovy",
>   "scriptOnResourceScriptFileName": null,
>   "scriptBaseClass": null,
>   "verbose": false,
>   "createScriptFileName": "CreateScript.groovy",
>   "recompileGroovySource": false,
>   "tolerance": 10,
>   "syncScriptFileName": "SyncScript.groovy"
>   },
>   "operationTimeout": {
>   "CREATE": -1,
>   "UPDATE": -1,
>   "DELETE": -1,
>   "TEST": -1,
>   "SCRIPT_ON_CONNECTOR": -1,
>   "SCRIPT_ON_RESOURCE": -1,
>   "GET": -1,
>   "RESOLVEUSERNAME": -1,
>   "AUTHENTICATE": -1,
>   "SEARCH": -1,
>   "VALIDATE": -1,
>   "SYNC": -1,
>   "SCHEMA": -1
>   },
>   "resultsHandlerConfig": {
>   "enableNormalizingResultsHandler": true,
>   "enableFilteredResultsHandler": true,
>   "enableCaseInsensitiveFilter": false,
>   "enableAttributesToGetSearchResultsHandler": true
>   },
>   "poolConfigOption": {
>   "maxObjects": 10,
>   "maxIdle": 10,
>   "maxWait": 150000,
>   "minEvictableIdleTimeMillis": 120000,
>   "minIdle": 1
>   },
>    "configurationProperties":
>       {
>         "xsdIcfFilePath" : "samples/sample1/data/resource-schema-1.xsd",
>         "xsdFilePath" : "samples/sample1/data/resource-schema-extension.xsd",
>         "xmlFilePath" : "samples/sample1/data/xmlConnectorData.xml",
>         "createFileIfNotExists": false
>     }
>   }

It result on the following stacktrace :

> WARNING: Resource exception: 500 Internal Server Error: "Internal Server Error"
>   org.forgerock.json.resource.InternalServerErrorException: Internal Server Error
>           at org.forgerock.openidm.provisioner.impl.SystemObjectSetService.actionInstance(SystemObjectSetService.java:340)
>           at org.forgerock.json.resource.Resources$SingletonHandler.handleAction(Resources.java:513)
>           at org.forgerock.json.resource.Router.handleAction(Router.java:208)
>           at org.forgerock.json.resource.FilterChain$Cursor.handleAction(FilterChain.java:57)
>           at org.forgerock.json.resource.Filters$ConditionalFilter.filterAction(Filters.java:52)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor131.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)

I think that the configuration is not fully proper but I don't know where...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just generated the proper configuration using this file :

```
    {
    "enabled" : true,
    "syncFailureHandler" : {
        "postRetryAction" : "logged-ignore",
        "maxRetries" : 5
    },
    "configurationProperties" : {
        "minimumRecompilationInterval" : 100,
        "scriptRoots" : [
            "tbd/tbd/tools"
        ],
        "customizerScriptFileName" : "CustomizerScript.groovy",
        "resolveUsernameScriptFileName" : "ResolveUsernameScript.groovy",
        "debug" : false,
        "disabledGlobalASTTransformations" : [
            null
        ],
        "scriptExtensions" : [
            "groovy"
        ],
        "updateScriptFileName" : "UpdateScript.groovy",
        "sourceEncoding" : "UTF-8",
        "searchScriptFileName" : "SearchScript.groovy",
        "scriptOnResourceScriptFileName" : "ScriptOnResourceScript.groovy",
        "scriptBaseClass" : null,
        "verbose" : false,
        "createScriptFileName" : "CreateScript.groovy",
        "tolerance" : 10,
        "readSchema" : false,
        "authenticateScriptFileName" : "AuthenticateScript.groovy",
        "warningLevel" : 1,
        "deleteScriptFileName" : "DeleteScript.groovy",
        "schemaScriptFileName" : "SchemaScript.groovy",
        "customConfiguration" : null,
        "targetDirectory" : null,
        "classpath" : "tbd/tbd/tools",
        "customSensitiveConfiguration" : null,
        "testScriptFileName" : "TestScript.groovy",
        "recompileGroovySource" : false,
        "syncScriptFileName" : "SyncScript.groovy"
    },
    "_id" : "provisioner.openicf/MYCONNECTOR",
    "objectTypes" : {
        "__ACCOUNT__" : {
            "id" : "__ACCOUNT__",
            "properties" : {
                "lastModified" : {
                    "nativeName" : "lastModified",
                    "flags" : [
                        "NOT_CREATABLE",
                        "NOT_UPDATEABLE"
                    ],
                    "type" : "string",
                    "nativeType" : "string"
                },
                "created" : {
                    "nativeName" : "created",
                    "flags" : [
                        "NOT_CREATABLE",
                        "NOT_UPDATEABLE"
                    ],
                    "type" : "string",
                    "nativeType" : "string"
                },
                "telephoneNumber" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "nativeName" : "telephoneNumber",
                    "nativeType" : "string"
                },
                "familyName" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "required" : true,
                    "nativeName" : "familyName",
                    "nativeType" : "string"
                },
                "__NAME__" : {
                    "nativeName" : "__NAME__",
                    "flags" : [
                        "NOT_UPDATEABLE"
                    ],
                    "type" : "string",
                    "required" : true,
                    "nativeType" : "string"
                },
                "userName" : {
                    "nativeName" : "userName",
                    "flags" : [
                        "NOT_CREATABLE",
                        "NOT_UPDATEABLE"
                    ],
                    "type" : "string",
                    "nativeType" : "string"
                },
                "emailAddress" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "nativeName" : "emailAddress",
                    "nativeType" : "string"
                },
                "givenName" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "nativeName" : "givenName",
                    "nativeType" : "string"
                },
                "displayName" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "required" : true,
                    "nativeName" : "displayName",
                    "nativeType" : "string"
                },
                "password" : {
                    "nativeName" : "password",
                    "flags" : [
                        "NOT_UPDATEABLE",
                        "NOT_READABLE",
                        "NOT_RETURNED_BY_DEFAULT"
                    ],
                    "type" : "string",
                    "nativeType" : "string"
                },
                "groups" : {
                    "type" : "array",
                    "nativeName" : "groups",
                    "items" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "nativeType" : "string"
                    },
                    "nativeType" : "string"
                }
            },
            "type" : "object",
            "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
            "nativeType" : "__ACCOUNT__"
        }
    },
    "poolConfigOption" : {
        "maxWait" : 150000,
        "minIdle" : 1,
        "maxIdle" : 10,
        "minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" : 120000,
        "maxObjects" : 10
    },
    "name" : "TBD",
    "connectorRef" : {
        "connectorHostRef" : "#LOCAL",
        "connectorName" : "org.forgerock.openicf.connectors.groovy.ScriptedConnector",
        "bundleName" : "org.forgerock.openicf.connectors.groovy-connector",
        "displayName" : "Groovy Connector",
        "bundleVersion" : "1.4.1.0"
    },
    "operationTimeout" : {
        "TEST" : -1,
        "UPDATE" : -1,
        "CREATE" : -1,
        "SCRIPT_ON_RESOURCE" : -1,
        "GET" : -1,
        "AUTHENTICATE" : -1,
        "SEARCH" : -1,
        "SCHEMA" : -1,
        "DELETE" : -1,
        "SYNC" : -1,
        "RESOLVEUSERNAME" : -1,
        "VALIDATE" : -1,
        "SCRIPT_ON_CONNECTOR" : -1
    },
    "resultsHandlerConfig" : {
        "enableAttributesToGetSearchResultsHandler" : true,
        "enableCaseInsensitiveFilter" : false,
        "enableFilteredResultsHandler" : true,
        "enableNormalizingResultsHandler" : true
    }
}
```